# What language/classes do I need to make a simple card game?

Tags: java, c++

How should i go about making a simple card game? (e.g. solitaire) I am familiar w/ terminal programs in java and c/c++, but i am not familiar w/ the graphical side. Is openGL too complex for a simple card game? I guess ultimately I'm asking where do I start? What language & functions do I need?

Comment: If you want to keep it simple use Java. Asking what functions you need is like asking what kind of hammer you need to build a house. An answer won't really get you anywhere.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

JavaFX 2 or Qt are really easy to start with, just look at the tutorials.

Answer (score 2):

Netbeans comes prepackaged with a GUI Builder. If you like drag and drop and can write your own java listeners behind it, this is not a bad option.

http://netbeans.org/features/java/swing.html